# The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

DropdownButton(
value: value,
items: locationItems,
onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
this.value = value;
print(value);
}),
),

for(int i = 0;i<widget.locationLength;i++){
locationItems.add(
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Text(
widget.locationName
),
value: "${widget.locationName}",
)
);
}

Answer (score 0):

you need to add type to the dropdown button

```dart
DropdownButton<String>( value: value,
 items: locationItems,
 onChanged: (value) => setState(() { 
         this.value = value;
         print(value);
       }),
 ),
```

and you also must ensure that `locationItems` is of type `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?`. you can do this by adding type to `DropdownMenuItem` when adding to list like this:

```dart
locationItems.add( DropdownMenuItem<String>( 
   child: Text( widget.locationName ), 
    value: "${widget.locationName}",
   )
);
```

or by strongly type `locationItems` when declaring it.

```dart
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? locationItems;
```